# How to create a teams card using external webservice and post data

Tags: microsoft-teams, adaptive-cards

I have created an outgoing webhook for my teams channel.
When user enters @aa it calls my external web service and server responds with an adaptive card.

```
           {
            "type": "message",
            "attachments": [
                {
                    "contentType": "application/vnd.microsoft.card.adaptive",
                    "content": {
            "$schema": "http://adaptivecards.io/schemas/adaptive-card.json",
            "type": "AdaptiveCard",
            "version": "1.3",
            "body": [
                {
                    "type": "TextBlock",
                    "size": "Medium",
                    "weight": "Bolder",
                    "text": " Project Management Hours",
                    "horizontalAlignment": "Center",
                    "wrap": true
                },
                                    {
                    "type": "TextBlock",
                    "size": "Medium",
                    "weight": "Bolder",
                    "text": " Notes",
                    "horizontalAlignment": "Left",
                    "wrap": false
                },
                {
                    "type": "Input.Text",
                    "isMultiline": true,
                    "id": "MultiLineVal"
                }
               ],
            "actions": [
                {
                    "type": "Action.Submit",
                    "title": "Submit",
                    "associatedInputs": "Auto"
                    "data": {
                        "id": "1234567890"

                },
            ]
        }
                }
            ]
        }';
```

The user in teams is present with this form.  When they click submit, I want the data collected from the form sent back to the same webservice.  How do i accomplish this?

Comment: You could deliver the adaptive card via PowerAutomate and it could do all of the work. Once the button is clicked, it could report the users response back to your web service, make sense?

Comment: As per the documentation "Adaptive Card in Outgoing Webhooks only support openURL card actions". Please go through this documentation for more details - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftteams/platform/webhooks-and-connectors/how-to/add-outgoing-webhook?msclkid=26eae3b3bf0311ecadb5f7aac49db534&tabs=urljsonpayload%2Cdotnet

Comment: @Skin my original card has some custom data that comes from my web service, can i get that data from inside powerautomate?

Comment: Yeah, you’d just send a payload to the PA flow and then construct the card in the flow adding your custom data as need be.

Answer (score -1):

[@Meghana-MSFT](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71886881/how-to-create-a-teams-card-using-external-webservice-and-post-data#comment127072537_71886881) is correct.

> Adaptive Cards in Outgoing Webhooks only support openURL card actions.

For more information, please review the documentation [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftteams/platform/webhooks-and-connectors/how-to/add-outgoing-webhook?msclkid=26eae3b3bf0311ecadb5f7aac49db534&tabs=urljsonpayload%2Cdotnet).